# Using Ext.js on node.js?

Tags: node.js, extjs

I'm using YUI at the moment on both browser and node.js side.

Is there a way to use Ext.js on node.js?

Comment: Using a framework designed for the _CLIENT_ on both the client & the server sounds like a _HORRIBLE_ idea.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424887/extjs-with-node-js-backend , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13526318/extjs-nodejs-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.alsonkemp.com/geekery/extjs-4-models-node-js/

Here's an example implementation, pulling in some data modelling classes. I haven't used either of these libraries, but a cursory glance at this and it seems the main idea is this:

```
fs = require('fs'); // filesystem module in Node.js

function injectJS(f) {
  eval(fs.readFileSync(f, encoding="ascii"));
}

injectJS('/path/to/my/includes/includeFile.js');

// now use the library as normal
```

Comment: They don't support it officially I guess :(

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a way.

Check out N-ext on GitHub: https://github.com/xcambar/n-ext

With the Node module, you'll be able to use all the Ext.core, Ext.util, Ext.data packages.

It also provides a proxy for MongoDB, so that you can CRUD the models you'll work with in your app.

HTH,

Answer (score 0):

A lighter and cleaner way: https://github.com/egorFiNE/node-extjs