# extjs with node.js backend?

Tags: node.js, extjs

Are there any projects, examples, tutorials, etc that would show ExtJS used with Node.js as the backend? I am looking specifically at multiple users collaborating in real-time, but anything with ExtJS and node together would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.alsonkemp.com/geekery/extjs-4-models-node-js/) is a example of ExtJS used with Node.js. There is another interesting project (server side javascript) called [SilkJS](http://www.silkjs.net/). You should have a look at it as well. [Here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?161210-Using-SilkJS-ORM-and-ExtJS-Grids-Together) is an example of using SilkJs and ExtJS.

Since Node.js is server side, you should not have any issues using it along with ExtJS. There is no dependency on server side for ExtJS.

Comment: I need realtime. If i could use standard http ajax requests, i can set that up much easier with a web framework like php. I was thinking along the lines of socket.io.

Comment: The example @Abdel is referring to truly is based on Silk JS but has been previously set up to work with Node JS and Websockets, which worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a example on Extjs with node at backend. Please go through the git

https://github.com/tsuryap/ExtJsAndNodeExample

Answer (score 0):

SilkJS is fast enough that it is real time; maybe more real-time than node even.

Anyhow, ExtJS does a lot of Ajax internally, FWIW.