# ExtJS + NodeJS mvc application

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, extjs

I would like to ask about use ExtJS inside NodeJS environment, I tried some node modules but no one allow me to create the application of extjs using thier mvc structure (I mean using Ext.application) do anyone have any luck with this?

Regards.

Comment: I'm interested in the same thing, but with the Dojo toolkit instead of Ext

Comment: There is extnode in npm by brunotavares, but doesn't allow to create an mvc arch app ;/

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary build of ExtJs will not work. `ext-core-debug.js` uses **window** and another browser builtin objects. To make it work you'll need to make some fakes: **window**, **navigator**, etc.